# preg_match(): Compilation failed: nothing to repeat at offset 2

Tags: php, regex, preg-match, currency

I can't figure out why my regular expression is breaking.

I want it to match:

$100,000

100,000

100000 (I know it doesn't match this, but I want it to)

```
preg_match("/^\$?(?!0.00)\d{1,3}(,\d{3})*(\.\d\d)?$/", $string);
```

So how can I make it match the last one too, and why am i getting this error? This regular expression works fine in my javascript check.

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to escape the backslash to make it literal, because it's escaping the dollar sign as part of PHP string syntax.

```
preg_match("/^\\\$?(?!0.00)\d{1,3}(,\d{3})*(\.\d\d)?$/", $string);
```

or use single quotes rather than double quotes:

```
preg_match('/^\$?(?!0.00)\d{1,3}(,\d{3})*(\.\d\d)?$/', $string);
```

To allow numbers without commas, you can use alternation:

```
preg_match('/^\$?(?!0.00)(\d{1,3}(,\d{3})*|\d+)(\.\d\d)?$/', $string);
```

Answer (score 2):

Add two slashes

```
preg_match("/^\\\$?(?!0.00)\d{1,3}(,\d{3})*(\.\d\d)?$/", $string,$matches);
               ^^
```

#### The code

```
<?php
$string='$100,000';
preg_match("/^\\\$?(?!0.00)\d{1,3}(,\d{3})*(\.\d\d)?$/", $string,$matches);
print_r($matches);
```

**`OUTPUT :`**

```
Array
(
    [0] => $100,000
    [1] => ,000
)
```

**Update:** If you want to match the numbers like `1`, `1000`, etc Then use below one, and notice the change:

```
preg_match("/^\\\$?(?!0.00)\d{1,3}(\,?\d{3})*(\.\d\d)?$/", $string,$matches);
                                     ^ here making the comma optional
```

Comment: Thanks, but now it says: "Undefined offset: 0"

Comment: Why does the error occur? Why does adding an escaped slash work?

Comment: Can you post your string ?

Comment: @ShankarDamodaran I think two `\\` will be fine. But still you guys know better `php` then me.

Comment: @SabujHassan, Am not that good at regex :) just learning . Please feel free to edit my answer.

Comment: @DylanCross, See the demo. https://eval.in/131867 . Can you post your code how to recreate that error ?

Comment: @ShankarDamodaran Not sure its the correct one or not. Let see how many `-1` my edit earns for you. lol.